# Refreshing Multiple Listbox with AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, listbox, coffeescript

I have a 2 multiple listboxes as shown below

[image]

When I select multiple values from left listbox and click right arrow it will move those values to right listbox and those values will be removed from left listbox.

Html

```
    <select multiple ng-model="selectedRoleValue">
        <option ng-selected="selectrole" ng-repeat="role in roles | filter:searchRoleOne" value="{{role}}">{{role}}</option>
    </select>
    <img src="./images/arrow.svg" ng-click="addToRightPan()">
    <select name="cars" multiple class="listMutiple top5" ng-model="removeRoleValue">                                
        <option ng-selected="selectrrole" ng-repeat="role in newRoleValue | filter:searchRoleTwo" value="{{role}}">{{role}}</option>
    </select>
```

coffeescript code

```
    $scope.roles = ["test role","test role1","test role2","test role3","test role4","test role5"]

    $scope.addToRightPan = ()->   
        $scope.temprole = $scope.roles
        for item in $scope.selectedRoleValue
            $scope.newRoleValue.push item
            t = $scope.temprole.filter (word) -> word isnt item
            $scope.temprole = t
        $scope.roles = $scope.temprole
        return
```

addToRightPan() is the function to move value from left Listbox to Right Listbox.

Functionality is working fine. However when i choose only on value from left listbox and move to right listbox an empty row is showing up in left listbox. But when i consoled values i couldn't find any empty values or anything.

In inspect element i found the following:

```
  <option value="? string:Account Cordinator ?"></option>
```

[image]

How can i remove it? Or is it possible to refresh the listbox explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working,

```
<select multiple ng-selected="selectrole" ng-model="selectedRoleValue" ng-options="role for role in roles | filter:searchRoleOne">
</select>
```

I changed ng-repeat to ng-options